# Who does air traffic control to the oceanic flights?

Tags: air-traffic-control, oceanic

ARTCC does air traffic control to the flights in their FIR. Then who does air traffic control to flights that are above the ocean(like pacific ocean or atlantic ocean)? 
Is there any FIR above the ocean too?
I want to know that what facility does air traffic control to the flights above the ocean.
Please let me know in detail. Thank you.

Comment: Related: [Who manages International Airspace Traffic?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/25215/3201) and [Where to download NATs (North Atlantic Tracks) information?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/32852/3201) and the illustration of when international cooperation doesn't work: [Why is there a strip of uncontrolled airspace between Russia and Norway?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/12810/3201)